# convert lists of string tuples to lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am facing a small problem in python which I am not able to solve quickly.

How to convert `a = ['(100,9),(200,10)']` (list of tupled strings)  to  `a = [(100,9),(200,10)]` (list of tuples)

I tried:

```
- [tuple(word) for word in a]
- a.strip("'")
- a.replace("'", " ")
```

None of above mentioned solutions are working for me.

Comment: Substitute *"tuple"* for *"dictionary"* when reading... Your string will become a tuple of tuples, but I'm sure you can figure out how to flatten it to whatever you need.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for duplicate. Thank you for making it clear and the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `literal_eval` func from `ast` module.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = ['(100,9),(200,10)']
>>> list(literal_eval(a[0]))
[(100, 9), (200, 10)]
```

Comment: Or `list(literal_eval(a[0]))`

Comment: Avinash - I got it. Thank you very much